# VBA Subfolders function only checks 1 level

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue with VBA .SubFolders functionality. From my understanding, it should return all the subfolders from a main folder, however, when I run the following code, it only returns the immediate subfolders:

```
Sub FileCheck()

Dim issuedFolder As String
Dim subFolder As Object
Dim file As Object

issuedFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Issued\"

If Dir(issuedFolder, vbDirectory) <> "" Then

    For Each C In Worksheets("Final Data Set").Range("D2:D1000")
        If C.Value <> "" Then


            For Each subFolder In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(issuedFolder).Subfolders
                For Each file In subFolder.Files
                    If (file.Name Like Left(C.Value, InStrRev(C.Value, "_")) & "*") Then
                        MsgBox ("Found: " & Left(C.Value, InStrRev(C.Value, "_")))

                    End If

                Next file

            Next subFolder
        End If

    Next C

End If

End Sub
```

Before I start adding recursion into it, is there any way to adjust the subfolders function to get all subfolders and all subfolders of those folders, etc.

Comment: `SubFolders` is designed to only return the immediate subfolders. You need to use recursion, or a stack. `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` is on every PC with IE 5.5 and later (i.e. Windows 98/2000 and later), I'd early-bind, if I were you, and get the performance and Intellisense that comes with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifted from my documentation submission:

Early Bound (with a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime)

```
Sub EnumerateFilesAndFolders( _
    FolderPath As String, _
    Optional MaxDepth As Long = -1, _
    Optional CurrentDepth As Long = 0, _
    Optional Indentation As Long = 2)

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    'Check the folder exists
    If FSO.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
        Dim fldr As Scripting.Folder
        Set fldr = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)

        'Output the starting directory path
        If CurrentDepth = 0 Then
          Debug.Print fldr.Path
        End If

        'Enumerate the subfolders
        Dim subFldr As Scripting.Folder
        For Each subFldr In fldr.SubFolders
            Debug.Print Space$((CurrentDepth + 1) * Indentation) & subFldr.Name
            If CurrentDepth < MaxDepth Or MaxDepth = -1 Then
                'Recursively call EnumerateFilesAndFolders
                EnumerateFilesAndFolders subFldr.Path, MaxDepth, CurrentDepth + 1, Indentation
            End If
        Next subFldr

        'Enumerate the files
        Dim fil As Scripting.File
        For Each fil In fldr.Files
            Debug.Print Space$((CurrentDepth + 1) * Indentation) & fil.Name
        Next fil
    End If
End Sub
```